# Azure Iot Edge firmware and custom files inside

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-iot-hub, firmware, azure-iot-edge

I have device that works under Ubuntu server, there are two apps I created which is actually my "firmware"
My goal is to update those two apps by having Azure IoT Edge and create some kind of agent that send health and sensor status. I read couple of articles but still have questions:

1. How to create custom firmware that has two bin apps inside, unpack
   it on target device and move to particular folders?
2. Is it possible to write that agent in .NET CORE whether it is
   supported?

Appreciate in advance for any links regarding how to create custom firmware.

Comment: Do you want to create an IoT Edge module that  after deployment will just unpack 2 binaries into a specific location? 

Regading 2., it is possible to develop your module with .net core. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-csharp-module

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, but in order to be adequately answered I think you need to elaborate more on "My goal is to update those two apps by having Azure IoT Edge".
Azure IoT Edge is designed for developing local cloud gateways and enable you to do some on-the-edge processing of data. The technology is built upon docker containers. You can create custom .net core modules that could manipulate files through correct docker mappings. Furthermore, IoT Edge itself maintains live connection with Azure IoT Hub where you can check the indicative status of the device and its modules. However, the best practice suggests that you constantly send custom heartbeat messages which can contain whatever health information you want.

That is more like an introduction, but for a more precise and specific answer please elaborate on "My goal is to update those two apps by having Azure IoT Edge".